# Deploying the converted R-CNN Detector from Matlab to ONNX TO raspberry

Tags: matlab, deployment, onnx

I am working on a project using R-CNN detector (Regional convolutional neural network) for object detection. I created the detector and trained by Matlab and tested and it works fine however when I come to the stage to test it and deploy it to raspberry, the Matlab does not support the deployment of this detector to hardware. I saw many resources that it can be converted to ONNX format. I have already converted the Matlab file to ONNX file and now I am looking for the steps to use this onnx file and deploy to raspi, therefore,

I am looking for your support to deploy the pre-trained detector.

Answer (score 0):

Your ONNX file can be used with the ONNX Runtime Inference engine, following the [ARM 32 Dockerfile build instructions](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/master/dockerfiles/README.md#arm-32v7).

Related Stack Overflow answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59725880/10897861