# How to load or infer onnx models in edge devices like raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, onnx

I just want to load onnx models in raspberry pi. How to load onnx models in edge devices?

Comment: Voting to close this questions as there is a [dedicated rasperry pi forum](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Chris32, Raspberry PIs are typical Linux systems so answer to the question would be "load them the same way you load them on PC". But question lacks any details about runtime (python, c++, rust, go, etc) so I would consider it as too broad.

Comment: Rust and c++ runtimes are used

Answer (score 9):

You can use ONNX Runtime for ONNX model inference in Raspberry Pi. It support Arm32v7l architecture. Pre-build binary is not provided as of 2020/1/14. So you need to build it from source code. Instruction is described below.
https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/master/dockerfiles/README.md#arm-32v7

1. Install DockerCE on your development machine by following the instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/)
2. Create an empty local directory

```
mkdir onnx-build
cd onnx-build
```

3. Save the Dockerfile to your new directory

[Dockerfile.arm32v7](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/master/dockerfiles/Dockerfile.arm32v7)

```
FROM balenalib/raspberrypi3-python:latest-stretch-build

ARG ONNXRUNTIME_REPO=https://github.com/Microsoft/onnxruntime
ARG ONNXRUNTIME_SERVER_BRANCH=master

#Enforces cross-compilation through Quemu
RUN [ "cross-build-start" ]

RUN install_packages \
    sudo \
    build-essential \
    curl \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    wget \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-dev \
    git \
    tar \
    libatlas-base-dev

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip3 install --upgrade wheel
RUN pip3 install numpy

# Build the latest cmake
WORKDIR /code
RUN wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.14.3/cmake-3.14.3.tar.gz
RUN tar zxf cmake-3.14.3.tar.gz

WORKDIR /code/cmake-3.14.3
RUN ./configure --system-curl
RUN make
RUN sudo make install

# Set up build args
ARG BUILDTYPE=MinSizeRel
ARG BUILDARGS="--config ${BUILDTYPE} --arm"

# Prepare onnxruntime Repo
WORKDIR /code
RUN git clone --single-branch --branch ${ONNXRUNTIME_SERVER_BRANCH} --recursive ${ONNXRUNTIME_REPO} onnxruntime

# Start the basic build
WORKDIR /code/onnxruntime
RUN ./build.sh ${BUILDARGS} --update --build

# Build Shared Library
RUN ./build.sh ${BUILDARGS} --build_shared_lib

# Build Python Bindings and Wheel
RUN ./build.sh ${BUILDARGS} --enable_pybind --build_wheel

# Build Output
RUN ls -l /code/onnxruntime/build/Linux/${BUILDTYPE}/*.so
RUN ls -l /code/onnxruntime/build/Linux/${BUILDTYPE}/dist/*.whl

RUN [ "cross-build-end" ]
```

4. Run docker build

This will build all the dependencies first, then build ONNX Runtime and its Python bindings. This will take several hours.

```
docker build -t onnxruntime-arm32v7 -f Dockerfile.arm32v7 .
```

5. Note the full path of the .whl file

   - Reported at the end of the build, after the # Build Output line.
   - It should follow the format onnxruntime-0.3.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv7l.whl, but version number may have changed. You'll use this path to extract the wheel file later.
6. Check that the build succeeded

   - Upon completion, you should see an image tagged onnxruntime-arm32v7 in your list of docker images:

```
docker images
```

7. Extract the Python wheel file from the docker image

(Update the path/version of the .whl file with the one noted in step 5)

```
docker create -ti --name onnxruntime_temp onnxruntime-arm32v7 bash
docker cp onnxruntime_temp:/code/onnxruntime/build/Linux/MinSizeRel/dist/onnxruntime-0.3.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv7l.whl .
docker rm -fv onnxruntime_temp
```

This will save a copy of the wheel file, onnxruntime-0.3.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv7l.whl, to your working directory on your host machine.

8. Copy the wheel file (onnxruntime-0.3.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv7l.whl) to your Raspberry Pi or other ARM device
9. On device, install the ONNX Runtime wheel file

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
pip3 install numpy

# Install ONNX Runtime
# Important: Update path/version to match the name and location of your .whl file
pip3 install onnxruntime-0.3.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv7l.whl
```

10. Test installation by following the instructions [here](https://microsoft.github.io/onnxruntime/)

Comment: While the link may answer the question, please could you outline the instructions yourself in case the link stops working in the future?